# Positivity of the ramification divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, surfaces, normalization

Let $X$ be a non-normal surface such that $K_X$ is a pseudo-effective divisor
and ${\rm Bs}_{-}(K_X)$ (the diminished base locus of $K_X$) equals, at least set-theoretically, the non-normal locus of $X$. Consider $Y\rightarrow X$ to be the normalization of $X$.

Is it true that ${\rm Bs}_{-}(K_Y)$ equals, at least set-theoretically, the ramification divisor?

In other words, can the ramification divisor be positive enough such that it changes the diminished base locus of a non-normal variety when it is normalized?